# What is meant by complexity of O(log n)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Consider [this](https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/11350899_397629697090019_1329031682681797532_n.jpg?oh=45f1b21e50ee2ff6b3624ce08729052d&oe=55C3EDB7&__gda__=1438656783_2e88713da0a9aff844d87ab986b14c17) example of binary search tree.

```
n =10 ;and if base = 2 then
```

> log n = log<sub>2</sub>(10) = 3.321928.

I am assuming it means 3.321 steps(accesses) will be required at max to search for an element. Also I assume that BST is balanced binary tree.

Now to access node with value 25. I have to go following nodes:

```
50
40
30
25
```

So I had to access 4 nodes. And 3.321 is nearly equal to 4.

Is this understanding is right or erroneous?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @KarolyHorvath This question is about a specific case but that link does not deal with that specific case.

Comment: O(log n) means that time (or some other measure of complexity) has a value whose *upper bound* (after subtracting any constant portion) is *proportional* to log n.  (This means that, for small `n` values, it can easily be the case that an O(n^2) algorithm is faster than O(log n) one.  It's just as `n` grows the O(log n) version will not grow as fast.)

Comment: @user4913383: obviously. your comment is just noise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd call your understanding not quite correct.

The big-O notation does not say anything about an exact amount of steps done. A notation `O(log n)` means that something is approximately proportional to `log n`, but not neccesarily equal.

If you say that the number of steps to search for a value in a BST is `O(log n)`, this means that it is approximately `C*log n` for some constant `C` not depending on `n`, but it says nothing about the value of `C`. So for `n=10` this never says that the number of steps is 4 or whatever. It can be 1, or it can be 1000000, depending on what `C` is.

What *does* this notation say is that if you consider two examples with different and big enough sizes, say `n1` and `n2`, then ratio of the number of steps in these two examples will be approximately `log(n1)/log(n2)`.

So if for `n=10` it took you, say, 4 steps, then for `n=100` it should take approximately two times more, that is, 8 steps, because `log(100)/log(10)=2`, and for `n=10000` it should take 16 steps.

And if for `n=10` it took you 1000000 steps, then for `n=100` it should take 2000000, and for `n=10000` — 4000000.

This is all for "large enough" `n` — for small `n`s the number of steps can deviate from this proportionality. For most practical algorithms the "large enough" usually starts from 5-10, if not even 1, but from a strict point of view the big-O notation does not set any requirement on when the proportionality should start.

Also in fact `O(log n)` notation does not require that number of steps growths proportionally to `log n`, but requires that the number of steps growths *no faster* than proportionally to `log n`, that is the ratio of the numbers of steps should not be `log(n1)/log(n2)`, but `<=log(n1)/log(n2)`.

Note also another situation that can make the background for O-notation more clear. Consider not the number of steps, but the *time* spent for search in a BST. You clearly can not predict this time because it depends on the machine you are running on, on a particular implementation of the algorithm, after all on the units you use for time (seconds or nanoseconds, etc.). So the time can be 0.0001 or 100000 or whatever. However, all these effects (speed of your machine, etc) routhly changes all the measurement results by some constant factor. Therefore you *can* say that the time is `O(log n)`, just in different cases the `C` constant will be different.

Comment: Very clear and correct explanation. I am deleting my answer now. Upvoted yours. A request to OP to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is **not** correct totally. The steps/accesses which are considered are for comparisons. But, O(log n) is just a mere parameter to measure asymptotic complexity, and not the exact steps calculation. As exactly answered by **`Petr`**, you should go through the points mentioned in his answer.

Also, BST is binary search tree,also sometimes called ordered or sorted binary trees.

*Exact running time/comparisons can't be derived from Asymptotic complexity measurement. For that, you'll have to return to the exact derivation of searching an element in a BST.*

Assume that we have a “balanced” tree with n nodes. If the maximum number of comparisons to find an entry is (k+1), where k is the height, we have

```
2^(k+1) - 1 = n
```

from which we obtain

> k = log<sub>2</sub>(n+1) – 1 = O(log<sub>2</sub>n).

As you can see, there are other constant factors which are removed while measuring asymptotic complexity in worst case analysis. So, the complexity of the comparisons gets reduced to O(log<sub>2</sub>n).

Next, demonstration of how element is searched in a BST based on how comparison is done :-

```
1. Selecting 50,if root element  //compare and move below for left-child or right-child
2. Movement downwards from 50 to 40, the leftmost child
3. Movement downwards from 40 to 30, the leftmost child
4. Movement downwards from 30 to 25, found and hence no movement further.
// Had there been more elements to traverse deeper, it would have been counted the 5th step.
```

Hence, it searched the item 25 after 3 iterative down-traversal. So, there is 4 comparisons and 3 downward-traversals(because height is 3).

Comment: By one step/access I meant getting reference of a node. Also I counted root's reference too.

Node(root) 50's reference: 1
Node 40's reference: 1
Node 30's reference: 1
Node 20's reference: 1
Total = 4. 
But yes with respect to down traversal Total would be equal to 3

Comment: @user4913383-Sorry, you were right about the no. of comparisons --- the references(comparisons are done on references) are evaluated. I checked the other links on the internet. And, your question is really very good. I have made the necessary edits.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you say something like this :-

> Given a balanced binary search tree with n elements, you need O(log n) operations to search.

or

> Search in a balanced binary search tree of n elements is in O(log n).

I like the second phrase more, because it emphasizes that `O` is a function returning a set of functions given `x` (short: `O(x)`).  `x: N → N` is a function. The input of `x` is the size of the input of a function and the output of `x` can be interpreted as the number of operations you need.

An function `g` is in `O(x)` when g is lower than `x` **multiplied by an arbitrary non-negative constant** from some starting point n_0 for all following n.

In computer science, `g` is often set equal with an algorithm which is wrong. It might be the number of operations of an algorithm, given the input size. Note that this is something different.

More formally:

[image]

So, regarding your question: You have to define what `n` is (conceptually, not as a number). In your example, it is eventually the number of nodes or the number of nodes on the longest path to a leaf.

Usually, when you use Big-O notation, you are not interested for a "average" case (and especially not for some given case) but you want to say something about the worst case.

Comment: @shekharsuman A typo. I fixed it. Please focus on the important part of my answer: You cannot make any statement about actual number of operations given only a Big-O notation.

Comment: @shekharsuman BST can be unbalanced; actually, search in a BST is Θ(n) in the worst case.

Comment: Big-O notation denotes set of functions, not "function returning a set of algorithms".

Comment: You write `O(x)`. So `O` is a function which takes `x` as input and returns a set of functions. I try to rewrite it to be more explicit.

Comment: @effeffe Ah, now I see your point. I rephrased it, now it should be correct.

Comment: No, it's not a function, that's just notation, the presence of parentheses doesn't mean it's a function. In fact, later in your answer you (correctly) define the O(f) as a *set*, not a function. Also, those are set of *functions*, not algorithms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78631/discussion-between-moose-and-effeffe).